# How to use fold on an elaborate function in ocaml

Tags: tuples, ocaml, fold

As the title suggests, I want to use fold. If I understand correctly, it it used to apply a function to every item in a list. That's what I want to do with my function, but I don't know how to format it.

Here is the function I want to use with fold :

```
let pairing list =
let rec aux counter length paired list = match list with
| [] -> paired
| [head] -> paired
| head :: head' :: tail -> if counter = length then aux (counter-1) length ((head, head) :: paired) (head :: head' :: tail) else aux counter length ((head, head') :: paired) (head' :: tail)
in List.rev(aux (List.length(listheads list)) (List.length(listheads list)) [] (listheads list));;
```

What it does is it returns a list of all the items in the list paired together.

For example, if my list is `[3;4;2]`, it should return

```
[(3,3); (3,4); (3,2); (4,3); (4,4); (4,2); (2,3); (2,4); (2,2)]
```

What it returns at the moment is only `[(3,3); (3,4); (3,2)]`, because the function only applies to the first item of the list.

Here are all the helper functions :

```
let rec member list x = match list with
| [] -> false
| head :: tail -> head = x || member tail x

let head_list list =
let rec aux l1 list = match list with
 | [] -> l1
 | (x,y) :: tail -> aux (x :: l1) tail
in List.rev (aux [] list);;

let head'_list list =
let rec aux l2 list = match list with
 | [] -> l2
 | (x,y) :: tail -> aux (y :: l2) tail
in List.rev (aux [] list);;

let listheads list =
let rec aux returnlist l1 l2 = match l1 with
| [] -> returnlist
| head :: tail -> if member l2 head = true && member returnlist head = false then aux (head :: returnlist) tail l2 else aux returnlist tail l2
in List.rev(aux [] (head_list list) (head'_list list));;
```

What `listheads` does is it will take my original list (say `[(3,4); (4,2); (2,3); (4,7); (9,4)]`), use `head_list` and `head'_list` in order to determine which integers are both in `head` and `head'` position in the tuple, and put them in the list (in the case I gave, `[3;4;2]`).

I know that `fold` takes a function, an empty list and a list as arguments, but I don't know how to use pairing with fold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code need to make a double pass on the list

```
   let pairing l =
     let second_pass x acc y = ......  in
     let first_pass  acc el = .......  in
     List.fold_left first_pass [] l |> List.rev
```

The first pass function should call the second pass function, and the second pass function will create the pair element. Free to you for completing the code of the two functions.

Here the result I have :

```
    utop # pairing [3 ; 4 ; 2];;
    - : (int * int) list =
    [(3, 3); (3, 4); (3, 2); (4, 3); (4, 4); (4, 2); (2, 3); (2, 4); (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to answer your question because there's no clean place to add a fold to get the result you want.

It might be more fruitful just to debug your code. It seems to me you're using your counter backwards. Its initial value is the length of the list and it is decremented for each recursive call. But your test for termination tests against the length of the list. It seems to me you should be testing against 0 (or possibly 1).

If you have a function `f` that does something interesting to a value, and you have a list of the values, you can use `List.map` to get a list of the values of `f` applied to each element of the list. You don't need a fold for that.

The purpose of a fold is to compute thing other than just a list of the function values. For examle, if each call to `f` makes a list of values, you could use a fold to keep concatenating these lists into a longer list.

Let's say `f` makes a value `x` into a list `[x; x]`. Then you can create a (reversed) doubled list something like this:

```
let f x = [x; x]

let double l =
    let aux sofar x = f x @ sofar in
    List.fold_left aux [] l

# double [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [3; 3; 2; 2; 1; 1]
```

You could possibly follow this pattern if you can come up with a function like `f` that transforms a value into a list. If you define `f` inside your outer function it will have access to the initial list.